# fail to create account via php on mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I´m having trouble creating data onto a MySQL database via a php that I created in order to be able to create an account on a website I´m making I have the following php files that take care of the process (linked below), I have been looking to these lines of code for hours and I'm not able to figure out what is wrong with it ....

**signup.php**

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AlojArt Reservas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in

        require 'login.php';

    }

    elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering

        require 'register.php';

    }
}
?>

  <body class="login-bg">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                  <!-------------------- Logo -------------------->
                  <div class="logo">
                     <h1><a href="index.php">AlojArt Reservas</a></h1>
                  </div>

               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-wrapper">
                    <div id="register">
                        <div class="box">
                            <form action="signup.php" method="post" autocomplete="off"> 
                                <div class="content-wrap">
                                    <h6>Criar conta</h6>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome_titular">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nome de utilizador " name="username">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Palavra-passe" name="password">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Endereço de e-mail" name="email">
                                    <div class="action">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="register" />Criar conta</button>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </form>    
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="already">
                        <div id="login">
                            <p>Já tem conta?</p>
                            <a href="index.php">Iniciar sessão</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
session_start();

$_SESSION['nome_titular'] = $_POST['nome_titular'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

// Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injections
$nome_titular = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['nome_titular']);
$username = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['username']);
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

// Check if user with that email already exists
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Utilizador WHERE email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error());

// We know user email exists if the rows returned are more than 0
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

    $_SESSION['message'] = 'O utilizador jรก existe!';
    header("location: error.php");
}

else { // User doesn't already exist in a database, proceed...

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Utilizador (nome_titular, username, email, password)"
            . "VALUES ('$nome_titular','$username','$email','$password')";

    // Add user to the database
    if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header("location: dashboard.php");

    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "O registo falhou!";
        header("location: error.php");
    }

}

?>
```

EDIT: added db.php

**db.php**

```
<?php
/* Database connection settings */
$host = 'CENSORED';
$user = 'CENSORED';
$pass = 'CENSORED';
$db = 'projeto2_dcw';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
```

Comment: whats you problem? Cant you create a database connection or something else?

Comment: could you please show db.php

Comment: I always get redirected to the error.php with the message "O registo falhou!"

Comment: @PedroSilva put space `' '` without single quote before `"VALUES`

Comment: please show ur db.php

Comment: can you give an example @Ravi ?

Comment: @AmalJo added the db.php to the main post

Comment: is your db even connected ? where is mysqli_connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there is no space `' '` before `VALUES`, this would cause failure of SQL.

Change your SQL to

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Utilizador (nome_titular, username, email, password)"
        . " VALUES ('$nome_titular','$username','$email','$password')";
```

If you still getting unexpected result, then please put following code to `else` get the error and comment out everything else.

```
printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

**==Update==**

> "Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY"

It refers to `primary key` constraint violation, in other word, you are trying to insert new value `0`, which is already present in same column. Since, `primary key` doesn't allow duplicate. It is failing and falling to `else` block. To correct this issue, you need to make sure, you don't have duplicate entry for column which has `primary key`.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: @PedroSilva check out my post

Comment: I'm going to give it a shot!

Comment: got this error: "Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY"

Comment: @PedroSilva It is obvious then. Let me update my post

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no connection for your page thats why it gets redirected to error.php change your db connection to this

```
<?php
$host = 'CENSORED';
$user = 'CENSORED';
$pass = 'CENSORED';
$db = 'projeto2_dcw';
$con = mysqli_connect("$host,$user,$pass,$db") or die($mysqli->error);
mysqli_select_db($con,"your db name");
?>
```

in the form change button
   `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="register" />Criar` conta

```
ALTER TABLE Your table name
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Comment: also changed this on my db.php file and no luck... and when I try to login or create an account the page goes blank...

Comment: I am able to access the webpage but then I goes blank... you can see for yourself http://black9404.ihostfull.com/

Comment: we didnt select the database now try running the code

Comment: haha @PedroSilva you are using a button and you have not included submit to the button ,just give  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="register" />Criar conta</button>

Comment: I guess I found the error : Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'  how can i fix this ?

Comment: in your db give primary key and remove the null checkbox and check A.I